# Pair to mac in visual studio 2015 OPENSSH key not supported

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, ssh-keys

I need to develop Xamarin iOS app and need to pair my mac. But visual studio shows key OPENSSH not supported.

I have tried to key `BEGIN WITH PRIVATE KEY` changed to `BEGIN WITH RSA KEY` also. But still its shows openssh not supporting.

```
Error message key"OPENSSH" not supported

OS: WINDOWS 7,
Visual Studio 2015
```

Comment: can anyone solve this

Comment: Solve what? You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: how to pair mac for develop iOS applications in visual studio 2015

Comment: Why not use the latest Visual studio 2019?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT sir actually i have using Visual studio 2015 my question is Visual studio 2015 pair to mac working or Not.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/374945/key-openssh-is-not-supported.html) that issue was fixed in updates. Since you are using older versions of Visual Studio, you are facing that issue. Hope that answers your question